# linking django to web hosting site

Tags: python, django, dns, web-hosting

I have created a webpage using Django and am looking to link it to my purchased domain name through domain.com. Domain.com tutorials have been worthless and they offer web hosting but I am not sure how to link my local Django project. Does it have to do with the SSL Certificate? Feel free to explain it to me like I am a 5 year old.

I tried including the domain and ip of the purchased domain in the ALLOWED_HOSTS=[] but obviously that doesn't work without some communication between domain.com and Django.

Comment: you are gonna need to host your project somewhere, as in get a server. There are many ways to do that, the easiest is to use some managed service like `render` or `Heroku`, check out this tutorials https://render.com/docs/deploy-django for render for example

Comment: I don't think domain.com is really set up to serve your django project, so you should look elsewhere (render.com has a free plan which is easy to use so I would also recommend them as a place to start).

Comment: but i can still use my purchased domain name from domain.com, correct? thanks for the help

Comment: If you own the domain name as a rule yes you can still use it no matter where the site is hosted (although the details might depend on where you deploy your application I guess).